# Unable to initialize class in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

**Directory:**

Prototype

-app

-assets

-controllers

---welcome_controller.rb

domainobjects

---SimilarJob.rb

Utilities

--API.rb

**Controller Code**

```
require_relative '../domainobjects/SimilarJob'

class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
  foo = API.new('DEVKEY')
  res = foo.RetrieveFacts("Test", "Me")

  #newResult = SimilarJob.new("test") <-- Failing Line!!!

  render :text => res["Response"]["IsInternationalResponse"]
 end
end
```

**Object Code**

```
class SimilarJob
end
```

I stripped out some things, but the API class exists in a separate directory, "Utilities", and for some reason I don't even have to reference it using the "requires_relative" keyword. It's a wrapper class that includes HTTParty and makes a successful GET request to my external API every time. Can someone explain why I seemingly don't have to reference it anywhere?

Alternatively, attempting to initialize the SimilarJob class fails each time. The error is:

```
uninitialized constant WelcomeController::SimilarJob
```

From what I researched here and on the web, this means I'm not referencing the file correctly. To test this out, I tried naming it incorrectly in the "requires_relative" statement and the framework informs me that the requested file could not be loaded. So it seems like Rails is finding my class, it just won't initialize it for some reason.

The most maddening part is that I'll make a few small changes to SimilarJob, restart my server, and it'll work all of a sudden. If I stop and start the server again, it's back to the error I pasted below.

This is my first time really digging in something other than .NET MVC or KnockoutJS..would you guys mind pointing out the error of my ways?

EDIT: I used the generate command for this controller, so all views and routes work appropriately. In fact, if I comment out the problematic line, the property I'm referencing on the last line in my JSON response renders to the file just fine.

EDIT v2: Strangely enough..changing my class name to Jobs (one word) is getting rid of this error. This comes off as bizarre! Can anyone confirm that this is my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names matter, and you've named your file wrong. `SimilarJob.rb` needs to be `similar_job.rb`.

Similarly, your `API` file should be called `api.rb`, and the class it defines should be called `Api`. This stuff is important, as you've deviated badly from Rails convention, and are suffering for it.